Strange results while trying to make matris symmetric in Eigen
In my project i work with covariance matrices and during many repetitive operation i have noticed that they gradually loose their symmetry. I put it down to numerical problems and when loss of symmetry exceed some level i try to restore matrix to proper form. I found in stack a simple method:
matrix = (matrix + matrix.transpose()) / 2.0
But when implemented i got strange result. Bottom triangle have proper values, but top one is different. Consider example
Eigen::Matrix< double, 9, 9 > matrix;
matrix << 40559.778825, -31153.274570 , -2446.164237 , 17250.180423, -13036.183685 ,  -614.749476 ,  4145.292673,  -2929.325056 ,   -76.389702,
        -31163.652992 , 24642.034288 , -3155.954773 ,-13024.935948 , 10606.170622 ,  -793.926649 , -2912.511277  , 2669.226555 ,   -98.352932,
        -2446.293563 , -3155.849492,  81838.610505,   -618.601965 ,  -798.172922 , 20679.490319 ,   -80.854530 ,  -103.928341  , 2647.708959,
        17248.482322, -13019.753998 ,  -618.571123,  12761.733661 , -9040.721303,   -280.843475  , 5353.243186 , -3137.980275  ,  -66.415783,
        -13042.257916 , 10607.886484 ,  -798.195886 , -9042.370514  , 8146.254203 ,  -362.980644  ,-3133.173126 ,  3755.211086  ,  -85.807600,
        -614.817862 ,  -793.873126 , 20679.490338 ,  -280.857733  , -362.970017 ,  9637.963651 ,   -67.965019  ,  -87.712623 ,  2515.917137,
        4145.394398,  -2912.244650 ,   -80.851248  , 5353.380853,  -3133.239131  ,  -67.964682  , 4019.412600 , -1611.914593  ,  -29.487958,
        -2929.547642 ,  2669.130747 ,  -103.929154 , -3137.845462,   3755.074471 ,   -87.712468,  -1611.816127  , 3196.926413 ,   -38.111306,
        -76.393072 ,   -98.350422 ,  2647.708977,    -66.413746,    -85.809278 ,  2515.917141 ,   -29.487009  ,  -38.112091,   1382.242447;

    std::cout << std::fixed << matrix << std::scientific << "\n\n";
    matrix = (matrix + matrix.transpose()) / 2.0;
    std::cout << std::fixed << matrix << std::scientific << "\n"; // wrong upper triangle here

When separate helper matrix used all if fine
   Eigen::Matrix< double, 9, 9 > helper = (matrix + matrix.transpose()) / 2.0;
   matrix = helper;
   std::cout << std::fixed << matrix << std::scientific << "\n";

Where is a problem?

In the Eigen documentation for transpose, it says

If you want to replace a matrix by its own transpose, do NOT do this:
m = m.transpose(); // bug!!! caused by aliasing effect
Instead, use the transposeInPlace() method:
m.transposeInPlace();

In your code the original data gets overwritten during the computation, so part of the computation only sees the overwritten data, causing the issues you see.

Think of Eigen doing two big for loops around all coefficient for these kinds of expressions. So you'd effective have something like:
matrix = (matrix + matrix.transpose()) / 2.0;

become the equivalent of (but optimized)
for (int col = 0; col < matrix.cols(); ++col) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.rows(); ++row) {
        matrix(row, col) = (matrix(row, col) + matrix.transposed()(row, col)) / 2.0;
    }
}

which in turn is equivalent to:
for (int col = 0; col < matrix.cols(); ++col) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.rows(); ++row) {
        matrix(row, col) = (matrix(row, col) + matrix(col, row)) / 2.0;
    }
}

Note here that .transpose() just takes a reference to the underlying matrix, and its evaluation just leads to the coefficient access as described above. And that specific for loop is problematic, because you are modifying e.g. matrix(0, 1) before accessing it again when computing matrix(1, 0). Which is why you see the weird behavior you see where the results are correct for only one triangle.
This is also why adding two matrices is not a problem, because matrix1(row, col) = matrix1(row, col) + matrix2(row, col); doesn't have any side-effects for other coefficients, so each loop instance is completely independent of each other. But that is not the case for .transpose().
You have two options:

Create a temporary during the evaluation (this requires heap allocation if the matrix size is dynamic):
matrix = (matrix + matrix.transpose().eval()) / 2.0;

(or)
matrix = (matrix + matrix.transpose()).eval() / 2.0;

(or)
matrix = ((matrix + matrix.transpose()) / 2.0).eval();

(You'd have to test which one of these is the fastest; I suspect the last one.)

Write into a different target object (that may have been pre-allocated):
matrix2 = (matrix + matrix.transpose()) / 2.0;



See also the Eigen documentation on aliasing.
